# PHP+MySQL wrong syntax in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ham WHERE Call = $call";
```

I've tried with it all kinds of configurations with backticks and single quotes. Every time I get this:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL = LZ1IRQ' at line 1

'LZ1IRQ' is an actual value I set using an HTML form via POST.

```
$call = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['call']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALL` is reserved keyword in MySQL. I think you cannot use this keyword as you are using now. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html) official list of reserved keywords.

If you are required to use reserved key then you should wrap it in back-ticks.

Comment: I changed 'Call' to 'Callsign' in the DB and querries. But now I have another error in another querry.

$querry = "SELECT * FROM ham WHERE Callsign = $call";
Error1: Unknown column 'LZ1IRQ' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please confirm again that you wrapped it with backticks, not single apostrophe :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that I could be of some help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change  your query to this

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ham WHERE Call = {$call}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I can infer you are using mysqli so the best and most secure is to bind parameters, with this solution you prevent sql injection at the same time:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ham WHERE Call =?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $call);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ham WHERE `Call`  = '".$call."' ";
```